# Dependencies between two managed metadata columns

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, metadata

I need to create a dependency between two columns in a document library. The first column is "Exempt?". Either `"Yes"` or `"No"` can be input. If "Exempt?" is `"Yes"`, then I would like the second column `"Releaseable"` to be "No".  If "Exempt?" is `"No"`, then `"Releaseable"` should be "Yes".

Is it possible, without using any outside add-ons or programs, to create a dependency between the two?

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOTB to create metadata column dependencies. I am not sure how easy it is to write a solution for it.

If you are not using the Metadata column then it fairly easy. Check this

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/c4535103-d019-4e74-8529-39d8acf63a40/how-to-create-calculated-column-which-shows-yesno-sharepoint-2010